(Debian) Rsyslog unable to capture tls traffic on rsyslog
I am unable to capture tls/udp syslog (ports 443/514) via rsyslog on my debian bullseye. Appreciate any help regarding this!
I have gone through both Rsyslog through TLS and Rsyslog not capturing Remote log but it has not solved my problem.
Tcpdump gives clear logs on the other hand:
etc # tcpdump -i enp9s0 host <my_ip> and 'port 514'
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on enp9s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
13:39:25.327149 IP <client_ip>.63750 > <my_ip>.syslog: SYSLOG user.notice, length: 107
13:39:28.354475 IP <client_ip>.63750 > <my_ip>.syslog: SYSLOG user.notice, length: 99
13:39:31.375032 IP <client_ip>.63750 > <my_ip>.syslog: SYSLOG user.notice, length: 111

Here is my debian version:
# cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"

Here is my rsyslog config file:
# /etc/rsyslog.conf configuration file for rsyslog

#################
#### MODULES ####
#################

module(load="imuxsock") # provides support for local system logging
module(load="imklog")   # provides kernel logging support
# TLS certificate setup (ensure paths are correct)
global(
DefaultNetstreamDriver="lmnd_gtls"
DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile="/my_certs/ca_certificates/cacert1.pem"
DefaultNetstreamDriverCertFile="/my_certs/server_certificates/servercert1.pem"
DefaultNetstreamDriverKeyFile="/my_certs/server_keys/serverkey1.pem"
)

# load TCP listener
module(
load="imtcp"
StreamDriver.Name="gtls"
StreamDriver.Mode="1"
StreamDriver.Authmode="anon"
)

# start up listener at port 6514
input(
type="imtcp"
port="6514"
)



###########################
#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####
###########################

# Use traditional timestamp format.
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

# Set the default permissions for all log files.
$FileOwner root
$FileGroup adm
$FileCreateMode 0640
$DirCreateMode 0755
$Umask 0022

# Where to place spool and state files
$WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog

# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf

###############
#### CHANNELS ####
###############

# Output Channels to achieve log rotation and fixed-length syslog files
$outchannel rotated_syslog,/var/log/syslog,209715200,/opt/run/./log_rotate /var/log/syslog
$outchannel rotated_daemon,/var/log/daemon.log,209715200,/opt/run/./log_rotate /var/log/daemon.log
$outchannel rotated_userlog,/var/log/user.log,209715200,/opt/run/./log_rotate /var/log/user.log
$outchannel rotated_messages,/var/log/messages,209715200,/opt/run/./log_rotate /var/log/messages
$outchannel rotated_debug,/var/log/debug,209715200,/opt/run/./log_rotate /var/log/debug

###############
#### RULES ####
###############

# Standard log files. Log by facility.
auth,authpriv.*                 /var/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none          :omfile:$rotated_syslog
#cron.*                         /var/log/cron.log
daemon.*                        :omfile:$rotated_daemon
kern.*                          -/var/log/kern.log
lpr.*                           -/var/log/lpr.log
mail.*                          -/var/log/mail.log
user.*                          :omfile:$rotated_userlog

# Logging for the mail system. Split it up for easier script parsing.
mail.info                       -/var/log/mail.info
mail.warn                       -/var/log/mail.warn
mail.err                        /var/log/mail.err

# Some "catch-all" log files.
*.=debug;\ 
        auth,authpriv.none;\ 
        mail.none               :omfile:$rotated_debug
*.=info;*.=notice;*.=warn;\ 
        auth,authpriv.none;\ 
        cron,daemon.none;\ 
        mail.none               :omfile:$rotated_messages

# Emergencies are sent to everybody logged in.
*.emerg                         :omusrmsg:*

